# wamp magento no admin page

Tags: magento, wamp

I have a live magento website hosted in Bluehost, I just installed wamp and tried to clone the live website to local wamp server.

After some configuration changed from live server to local, the site is working with no problem, however, there is no admin page! If I go to localhost/magento/admin, it takes me to 404 page and throw error: 
The requested URL /magento/admin was not found on this server.

How do I fix this? Thanks lots.

Server info: wampserver2.2e-php5.4.3-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-32b

Comment: Don't use "localhost". And check that index.php should not be in the URL path.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that your server has no rewrites configured.

Try `http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin` - this should work. After that configure the rewrites in your server (enable mod_rewrite), so that everything works as intended.

And @benmarks is right - don't use `localhost` (i.e. server name without dots). The browser will display you admin login form, but there is a huge chance, that it won't be able to login you to the admin panel. You'd better change server name to something like `magento.local`.

Comment: Thank you, that is the point, however, I received new error message now: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt() in C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Http\Adapter\Curl.php on line 87

Comment: You need to enable curl extension in PHP - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards /viewthread/274194/

Comment: Thanks. I uncommented extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini, the problem persists

Comment: Did you restart server? Did you edit the right php.ini file (can be checked via phpinfo()).

Comment: Thanks for all replies, I am not a php expert and also don't know much how this stackoverflow controls my question/answer/reply. I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because admin values may changed in few tables. Please check the below tables and update.

```
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
    UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
    UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
    UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Hi Palanikumar, I ran your query, it doesn't return successful not failed msg, instead, the code in the text box will be changed to:

Answer (score 0):

in apache "httpd.conf" file find

"#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so"

and simply delete # sign to uncomment it. Then make .htaccess.sample file like .htaccess. This file located in magento root directory.